# Get UV coordinates of a 3D point , without actually applying a texture

Tags: python, mesh, texturing, uv

I want to get the UV coordinates of a plane in 3D, for use in some algorithm. How do I get that via python script, when my plane is untextured. The UV coordinates will be the same as the UV-mapping done when applying a texture to a plane, but I don't want to do the texture; just need the coordinates.

There are projection techniques that I can use to get UV coordinates, but I'm not keen on getting into the math of all that..Is there a direct way of getting the UV coordinates of an untextured object (a plane, for simplicity)?

Comment: Is your mesh uv-unwrapped? It's required.

Comment: No, I haven't done that.. how do I do that?

Comment: Go into edit mode of your object and press A until everything is selected , Press U and click "Smart UV project" , But it is better UV unwrap manually

Comment: And how can I get the UV coords for the mesh after the mesh was uv-unwrapped in python?